# Equality of function pointers which point to lambda function

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm wondering if the following behavior (see the assertions) is guaranteed by the C++ standard?
It seems that it works under the latest versions of clang and gcc but I'm still not sure if its standard defined behavior or implementation defined one.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

struct test
{
    using fn_ptr_t = int(*)(int);

    fn_ptr_t fn_ = nullptr;

    template<auto Fun>
    void assign() noexcept
    {
        fn_ = +[](int i)
        {
            return std::invoke(Fun, i);
        };
    }
};

int fun(int i) { return i; }
int gun(int i) { return i; }

int main()
{
    test t0, t1, t2;

    t0.assign<&fun>();
    t1.assign<&fun>();
    t2.assign<&gun>();

    assert(t0.fn_ == t1.fn_);
    assert(t0.fn_ != t2.fn_);

    return 0;
}
```

I found that the standard says the following about function pointers:

> C++03 5.10/1 [expr.eq]: ... Pointers to objects or functions of the
>   same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality.
>   Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are
>   both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same
>   address (3.9.2).

However, I'm not sure what is the situation when the function pointer points to a lambda function because the lambdas are said to be unique objects every time.

Comment: Looking for hints about this aspect of lambdas in C++03 is not going to be fruitful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that lambdas are unique, and this is exactly why the second assertion passes. But they are not always different on each evaluation:

```
template <typename>
auto get() { return []{}; }

auto l1 = get<int>();
auto l2 = get<long>();
auto l3 = get<int>();

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(l1), decltype(l2)>); // fails
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(l1), decltype(l3)>); // passes

// caveat: needs C++20
l1 = l2; // no, different lambdas
l1 = l3; // ok, same lambda
```

In your case, the function pointer of `t0` and `t1` is the same, because they were both assigned by `assign<&fun>`, in which the lambda has always the same type.

Since they have the same type they have the same `operator()` and thus both function pointers are the same (they point to the same `operator()`).

Comment: `l1 = l3` does not compile with latest `clang`/`gcc`.

Comment: I guess, I will accept that as an answer.
It doesn't answer specifically if this is a behavior guaranteed by the standard but the answer sounds logical enough to me and provides a another proof with the lambda assignments coming in C++20.

Comment: @PavelVazharov Yes it's guaranteed. This follows from the fact that lambdas have a unique type, that function templates generate functions and that the type of objects don't change. I guess I could provide quotes from the standard if you want.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It's fine as it is. It sounds logical that same instantiation of a function template generates the same lambda type.
Thanks for the help.